# How are lastIndex and sticky and end-of-input supposed to combine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Exec only starts matching from lastIndex (default: 0) when the sticky flag is on:

- `/o/y.exec('foo')` → `null`

But if I try matching end-of-input like this, it doesn't work:

- `/$/y.exec('foo')` → `[ '', index: 3, input: 'foo' ]`

But matching for {negative lookahead: any character} does what I'd expect, which I would also expect to be equivalent to end-of-input:

- `/(?![^])/y.exec('foo')` → `null`
- `/(?![^])/y.exec('')` → `[ '', index: 0, input: '' ]`

What's going on here?

Comment: What browser (version) do you use? `/$/y.exec('foo')` yields `null` for me.

Comment: @Bergi: sounds like chrome with experimental web features enabled

Comment: @Bergi I'm using node. Looks like the same thing happens in [chrome with experimental web features] too.